# EF Core Data Context injection across Projects

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core

I have project A which is a class library and project B that uses A. Project A is meant to be a generic helper library that can be used across projects (such as B).

The EF Core datacontext and the data entities need to be defined in project B (as they can vary by project) but I need to inject the datacontext in to constructors of service classes in Project A (which handle everything in a generic way).
In Project B I have the datacontext

```
public class MyDataContext : DbContext
    {
        public MyDataContext(DbContextOptions<MyDataContext> options): base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Test> Tests { get; set; }

    }
```

In project A I have class UnitOfWork that implements IUnitOfWork. In it's constructor I need to inject the datacontext. However since project A cannot reference project B (project A is meant to be generic), I cannot use the actual name of the datacontext in the parameter list. Since the datacontext inherits from DbContext, I tried

```
public UnitOfWork(DbContext dc){...}
```

In the startup of Project B, I have

```
services.AddDbContext<MyDataContext>(options =>
     {
          options.UseSqlServer("...<the connection string> ...");
     });
services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
```

Everything compiles but in runtime when the UnitOfWork needs to be created, I get the error

```
System.AggregateException: Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: IUnitOfWork Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: UnitOfWork': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext' while attempting to activate 'UnitOfWork'.)
```

The Inner Exception is

```
InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext' while attempting to activate 'UnitOfWork'.
```

Any help is deeply appreciated.

**EDIT**
I was asked for the UnitOfWork class details in the comments. So here it is

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
    {
        private readonly DbContext dc;
        private readonly IServiceProvider serviceProvider;

        public UnitOfWork(DbContext dc, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            this.dc = dc;
            this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        }
        public void BeginTransaction()
        {
            dc.Database.BeginTransaction();
        }

        public void BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel isolationLevel)
        {
            dc.Database.BeginTransaction(isolationLevel);
        }

        public void CommitTransaction()
        {
            dc.Database.CommitTransaction();
        }

        public void RollbackTransaction()
        {
            dc.Database.RollbackTransaction();
        }

        public bool IsTransactionActive()
        {
            return dc.Database.CurrentTransaction != null;
        }

        public async Task<bool> SaveAsync()
        {
            return await dc.SaveChangesAsync() > 0;
        }

        public bool Save()
        {
            return dc.SaveChanges() > 0;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you add the unit of work class?

Comment: Original Question Edited to include the details

Comment: You broke EF Core. Your problem isn't DI, it's the completely wrong way of using EF Core. A DbContext is already a multi-entity Unit-of-Work. A DbSet is already a repository. There's absolutely no reason to use explicit transactions. A DbContext caches all changes. If you don't call `SaveChanges` all changes are discarded. If you do, all changes are persisted using an internal transaction. No connection to the database is necessary until you either load data or call `SaveChanges`

Comment: The real solution here is to remove this code and simply use `MyDataContext` the way it's supposed to work. Inject it into your classes, and only call `SaveChanges` once to persist all cached changes. If you don't, all changes will be discarded as soon as `MyDataContext` is disposed. Something that your "unit of work" class can't do because it doesn't implement `IDisposable`.

Comment: In fact this "unit of work" is essentially an alias for `IDbTransaction` except it doesn't work as well and won't roll back in case of errors. Check [Using Transactions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions) in the EF Core documentation . As the paragraph on the default behavior explains `For most applications, this default behavior is sufficient. You should only manually control transactions if your application requirements deem it necessary.` Very few applications require this. The default behavior gives `transaction-per-requests` to all web apps

Comment: IMO in certain cases it is a good idea to abstract EF Core in an application. If he decides to use NoSQL instead of relational databases, the transition will be way easier that way. It could also simplify unit testing.

Comment: @fbede except none of the "generic repositories' do this, and definitely not this code. That's why "generic repository" over an ORM is considered an anti-pattern. EF Core is already a *higher* level abstraction than the data access objects typically used as "repositories". In this particular case using database transactions is a really big bug that will quickly result in deadlocks and blocking

Comment: Noone is talking about database transactions, it is just a 1:1 abstraction of EF core. You can use it the same as you use EF core's service classes (nothing is different in functionality, that's not what abstraction is for), but instead of having EF dependencies everywhere, you only have dependencies to your own interfaces.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos can you give some more informatie why generic repositories are an anti-pattern (when using these with an ORM)?

Comment: @WilkovanderVeen an ORM already implements repositories and UoWs. Check Gunnar Peipman's [No need for repositories and unit of work with Entity Framework Core](https://gunnarpeipman.com/ef-core-repository-unit-of-work/) although the problem is well known for a decade [Repository is the new Singleton](https://ayende.com/blog/3955/repository-is-the-new-singleton). What is passed as a "generic repository" isn't even that, it's a Data Access Object.

Comment: This is from microsoft's sample project for Asp.net apps and microservices: https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnWeb/tree/main/src/Infrastructure/Data

Comment: @WilkovanderVeen even worse, bringing us back to the 1990s using explicit transactions. This completely breaks the disconnected model used by EF Core, DataTable and even before that OLEDB disconnected RecordSets. Using an explicit transaction requires an explicit, open database connection. This means that locks will be kept for a long time, blocking other connections and applications. This leads to orders**s** of magnitude worse performance

Comment: Microsoft's own eShopOnContainers sample project uses a service to abstract ef core and also a generic repository. You should check it out, there are many important architectural patterns in this app. https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnWeb?WT.mc_id=dotnet-35129-website

Comment: @fbede what makes you think I haven't years ago? Or that it works the way you assume it does? Where's the explicit transaction? Or the injected *base* context?  Or even that this is a good design? Microsoft's Patterns & Practices has produced some rather complicated and unfortunate guidance in the past, things that they acknowledged were a bad idea

Comment: Still, noone is talking abput explicit transactions. For the rest: :D :D

Comment: @fbede in fact, what makes you think this is a Microsoft sample project? Those are external contributors and one of the is a speaker that actually pushes his own Repository library. If you check the `csproj` you'll see that `RepositoryBase<T>` comes from the `Ardalis.Specification.EntityFrameworkCore` package

Comment: @fbede `noone is talking abput explicit transactions.` what do you call `BeginTransaction` ?

Comment: In case of, for example an MVC application, I would suggest it would be a good approach to work without centralized repositories, but when building web-api's i dont want to have EF manage my database state, I want atomic operations for that.

Comment: @WilkovanderVeen EF Core operations are atomic. `SaveChanges` is atomic. Either everything is persisted or nothing. No modifications are made to the database until `SaveChanges` is called. In fact, there's not even a database connection. Simply using an injected DbContext gives you transaction-per-request. *On the other hand* if you use Dapper then yes, you do need to abstract that. Using a *specialized* instead of a generic repository would make that easier. If you use it to make multiple modifications you also need to use explicit transactions.

Comment: @WilkovanderVeen after all, if you use Dapper you probably don't want to retrieve an entire object just to update a property, you'd want to write `UPDATE Product Set Price=Price*@increase where CategoryId=@category` to update all products instead of getting them one by one and updating them

Comment: He is creating a 1:1 proxy class above DbContext, he does not necesseraly have to use every implemented method, he can still use savechanges only. Though I agree that these method implementations (with explicit transactions) could be deleted if unused

Comment: Apologies for having caused this argument. As you might have guessed, I have old code from the pre .NET Core and EF era that I have started to modernize. The code is WIP and the explicit transaction management code will go away. For the moment I have just plugged in EF transaction management code in the older interface just to be able to run the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `UnitOfWork` service depends on a `DbContext` type, not the derived `MyDataContext` type which is registered into DI.
So you have two options:

You can modify the UnitOfWork registration like this (tell the IoC container to instantiate UnitOfWork with MyDataContext):

```
services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork>(srp => new UnitOfWork(srp.GetRequiredService<MyDataContext>(), srp));
```

Or you can register `DbContext` into DI as well, so the DI container knows that when someone asks for a DbContext it should return MyDbContext:

```
services.AddScoped<DbContext, MyDataContext>();
```

Note that the `ServiceProvider` field seems to be unused in your `UnitOfWork` class.

Comment: `DbContext` is the base class for all EF Core contexts. Most applications have multiple contexts so registering `DbContext` won't work.A DbContext is essentially a bounded context in DDD terms, not a model of the database. It contains the entities needed to serve a specific use case or scenario.

Comment: The problem is the "unit of work" class itself and no DI magic will fix the fundamental problems

Comment: His MyDataContext class is a derived type of the DbContext class. His exception occures, because he has nothing registered as DbContext in DI, hence UnitOfWork can not be instantiated. The solution above fixes that exact problem. If you have multiple DbContext classes, then you should probably have multiple UnitOfWork classes as well, and the second solution above should still work. Nonetheless, the question does not mention multiple DbContext derived classes.

Comment: And why is it DI magic? Registering services into DI is the most basic concept of dependency injection.

Comment: You completely misunderstood how EF Core works, or what unit of work is for. A DbContext is already a unit of work and **doesn't** have to work with explicit database transactions. Besides, instead of having a separate UoW class per type (which isn't needed to begin with) you can have a single generic one. `DI magic` is the attempt to fix a problem that has nothing to do with DI by adding registrations just to get the code to run..... and fail the first time you try to save

Comment: No that is the problem, he registers the derived class (as itself), not the base class. If you want the IoC container to return the derived class when someone asks for the parent DbContext class, you have to explicitly tell the IoC container to do that.

Comment: So *don't* do that, don't try to inject the generic parent that's used by every single application. What you propose is little different than proposing to register `Object`

Comment: I think you are misundestanding what my solution is trying to do (and probably you are not familiar with IoC containers neither). You are fixated on the idea that making a UnitOfWork implementation above EF Core is a bad idea. It may be, may be not, but that is not what the question is about.

Comment: I understand what you propose and why it doesn't work. I use DI, ORMs and Entity Framework for 10 years. And have to fix the problems caused by code like this all the time. What you propose will only delay the crash for a while. It's similar to adding a `catch{}` to silence exceptions instead of fixing them

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? This solution fixes the problem the question was asked for. Your suggestions are subjective and have little to do with the actual problem. If you have a single DbContext (which the question suggests you have) the above two solutions work perfectly. If you have multiple DbContext implemenations, the second solution should still work.

Comment: I understand you don't like UnitOfWork implementations, but the question is really unrelated. You could have any other service class which asks for a DbContext (the base class) in it's constructor and the way of registering such a class is the way I wrote in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to make two changes. First was to explicitly register the service as suggested by @fbede

```
services.AddScoped<DbContext, MyDataContext>();
```

Now when we do this, we lose the convenience of setting the `DbContextOptionsBuilder` options via the `AddDbContext` Extension method.

So we need to override the `OnConfiguring` method in the datacontext to set the configurations options we need. For example:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString(<key>));
    }
```

Of course, `IConfiguration` is injected in the `MyDataContext` constructor

Comment: You could also try the modified way of registering the unitOfWork class I mentioned as alternative solution. That way you should not have to modify your DbContext implementation.

Comment: The fact you had to make such changes should be a big red warning sign. Your DbContext is hard-coded to use SQL Server. Instead of abstracting the storage technology, you hard-coded it. Instead of making testing easier by using eg an in-memory provider or in-memory database (eg SQLite in in-memory mode), you *have* to use an actual database. Or add more and more configuration code into your DbContext